# Manage Roles and Capabilities on Multi-site

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I am trying to enable some features for Subscriber user role in a eCommerce theme where originally had be set for Admin role and I like to modify that.  I tried AAM plugin but for this specific site it does not show those features so I can place a check or un-check them.
I know AAM or any alike plugin serve as an interface and there are ways to look through the files/codes to make this happen.
I found in wp-includes/capabilities.php is where this gets managed but I am assuming not for each specif site as I can't find anything about other sites in there.
Does each site have its own capabilities.php somewhere?

Comment: Each sites loads the capabilities and stores it as metadata.  You have to modify the metadata to modify the capabilities for a specific site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'd need to modify user roles on each site individually (if I'm understanding your question correctly).

There's a great plugin I use frequently called WPFront User Role Editor that allows you to check/uncheck user capabilities like you mentioned. The free version should be fine for what you're trying to do. I personally use the paid version just because I like to have the extra options when I need them, but 90% of the time the free one works fine.

[You can view the plugin here](https://wpfront.com/user-role-editor-pro/)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! This is much better than the one I got which is AAM.  This much more user-friendly.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome! I hope your project goes well for you :)

Answer (score 1):

AAM is by far more powerful and it's since version 6.3.0 fully compatible with WordPress multisite [as mentioned on its website](https://aamplugin.com/article/aam-and-wordpress-multisite-support).

It also has the functionality to sync capabilities/permissions across all sites on the network as described on the above mentioned article.